# How to add new single.php to wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I have created a new single.php called new-single.php. I want this to appear on the 'post attributes template' dropdown. How do I go about achieving this?

I have FTP access but am quite new to Wordpress development so keep it basic ;)

Thanks

Owen

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials about templates, like this one https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/06/wordpress-custom-page-templates/ . If you still have questions after reading through and following some of them, then edit your question with what your have tried and what happened and it will be much easier to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try add comments in your new-single.php:

```
/**
 * Template Name: New Single Page
 */
```

Also could you please show this [Wordpress Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/)